# Reverse ordering Laravel eloquent eager loaded collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, grouping, reverse

I have a collection of products for a particular order like this -> 
$products = $order->products()->with('store.seller')->get();

What I want to get is a $sellersCollection where, 
each $seller has $stores
each $store has $products

[$seller - stores - products]

How can it be done efficiently without making another db call.

Answer (score 0):

using eloquent relationship you can access this.use appropriate relationship hasOne() or hasMany() in your model.Ex. Seller->hasOne(store) and store->belongsTo(seller) like that.

Comment: I want the particular $sellers who are associated with the order just made and with all the info of the products buyer ordered like quantity. I have to make this call $products = $order->products()->with('store.seller')->get() as it is needed like this order.

Comment: read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships. may be this will help

Answer (score 0):

Doing with eloquent way you could get the desired results as

```
$sellers = Seller::with('stores.products')->get();
```

Above will return you all sellers with their related stores and each store with their related products

```
class Seller extends Model{

    public function stores(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Store', 'seller_id')
    }

}

class Store extends Model{

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'product_id')
    }

}
```

I believe order and products are related as m:m via pivot table so you could define their relation as  `belongsToMany`

```
class Product extends Model{

    public function orders(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')
    }

}
```

Edit *I want the particular $sellers who are associated with the order just made and with all the info of the products buyer ordered like quantity*

```
$sellers = Seller::with(['stores.products.orders' => function ($query) use ($orderId) {
                        $query->where('id', '=', $orderId);
                    }])
                    ->whereHas('stores.products.orders', function ($query) use ($orderId) {
                        $query->where('id', '=', $orderId);
                    })
                    ->get();
```

Comment: I want the particular $sellers who are associated with the order just made and with all the info of the products buyer ordered like quantity.

Comment: @RezwanulIslam see updated answer, also it would be good you could include your models definition in your question, so people can see how they are related to each other

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to make another DB call.

Comment: `$order->save();
$order->products()->attach($pivotData); // store_id - product_id - quantity
$orderProducts = $order->products()->with('store.seller')->get();
// now i want to notify all this sellers about the products ordered by a buyer in their different stores`